# MVC3 Windows input type="file" size limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, input

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  In my HTML View, I am using the standard Windows file input

```
<input style="border:thin solid #ccc;width:270px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" type="file" name="Name" id="Name"/>
```

It's working fine except for big files.  I can upload a 2mb file bit not a 4mb file.  Is there a max file size for this input type or can I set the maxsize somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the `maxRequestLength` in your web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
</system.web>
```

The value is in kilobytes. 4096 is actually the default value, your file might be slightly larger so maybe try a higher number.