# Cannot Uploading Image in MVC3 when I press the submit button and it does not go to POST action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, image, uploading

This is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()

    {
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /ManagePhotos/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Photo photo, HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // save as original size of image
                var newfileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_"
                                    + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var bigImagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/PublicPhotos/BigImages"), newfileName);
                file.SaveAs(bigImagePath);

                // save as thumbnail image
                var photoUploaded = new WebImage(bigImagePath);
                photoUploaded.Resize(width: 200, height: 150, preserveAspectRatio: true, preventEnlarge: true);

                var thumbImagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/PublicPhotos/ThumbImages"), newfileName);

                photoUploaded.Save(thumbImagePath);

            }

            db.Photos.Add(photo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
```

This is my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","ManagePhotos", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) 
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Photo</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("File name: ")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

}
```

My Question: When I press "Create" button , the webpage show me below:

> The connection was reset.
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>     If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>     If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I try to debug in Razor View , and lookup on this website and I did exactly the website showed me but I cannot figure at out. Please help me.

Comment: What is the size of the file you are trying to upload ?

Comment: If your file exceed 4MB, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822860/mvc3-windows-input-type-file-size-limit

Comment: yes, you are right, I did it. Thank you very much

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered

Answer (score 1):

Your action is expecting `HttpPostedFile` but you should be using `HttpPostedFileBase`

Also as stated in the comments you need to verify the size isn't too large you can do that in Javascript

```
function onSelectImage(e) {
    if (e.files[0].size > 256000) {
        alert('The file size is too large for upload');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}
```

This ensures an image is only 256K or less as an example

Comment: @Brandon Let me know if that helps you out any